# Draw line between two movable uiviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer, key-value-observing

I have a "scrollview" with nodes (`UIViews`) that can be dragged around. I am trying to draw edges between selected `UIViews` with a "calayer", but I can't figure out how to redraw the line when a views position have changed.

In my `viewController` class I add the edge between first and second in the nodes array as:

```
EdgeLayer *edge = [[EdgeLayer alloc]init];
edge.delegate = self;
edge.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.25 alpha:1.0];
edge.strokeWidth = 0.5;
edge.startNode = [nodes objectAtIndex:0];
edge.endNode = [nodes objectAtIndex:1];
edge.frame = scrollView.bounds;
[scrollView.layer addSublayer:edge];
[edge setNeedsDisplay];
```

`EdgeLayer.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface EdgeLayer : CALayer
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *fillColor;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat strokeWidth;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *strokeColor;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *startNode;
@property (nonatomic) UIView *endNode;
@end
```

`EdgeLayer.m`:

```
#import "EdgeLayer.h"
#import "NodeView.h"

@implementation EdgeLayer

@synthesize fillColor, strokeColor, strokeWidth;
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
    self.fillColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    self.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    self.strokeWidth = 1.0;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

return self;
}

- (void) setStartNode:(NodeView*)startNode
{
     _startNode = startNode;
     [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) setEndNode:(NodeView*)endNode
{
    _endNode = endNode;
    [endNode addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"endNode" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
 }

-(id)initWithLayer:(id)layer
{
    self = [super initWithLayer:layer];
    return self;
}

-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:    (NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"endNode"] )
    {
    // process here
    }
    NSLog(@"View changed its geometry");
}

- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    NSLog(@"DRAW");

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, _startNode.center.x, _startNode.center.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, _endNode.center.x, _endNode.center.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
@end
```

This adds a line from the first and second nodes center position. I have tried to add an observer for the end node, but I don't think that I'm doing it right. I can't trigger the `observeValueForKeyPath` method. My guess is that I added the observer in the wrong place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not where you add the observer, but what you're tying to observe -- you're using endNode as the keyPath on endNode which won't work (endNode isn't changing as you drag anyway). The property of endNode that you want to observe is the center.

You only then need to change the keyPath you're observing to "center", and change your implementation of observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: like so,

```
-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"center"] ) [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I tested this by adding a pan gesture recognizer to one of the nodeViews, and the line connecting the two nodes was updated appropriately as I dragged.

Comment: thanks for the help. Actually pretty simple, must have been tired when trying to understand it. I just have one more question. How and when should i remove an observer? I might want to remove nodes and then i would need to remove the line and its observer or?

Comment: @freddy, if you're removing nodes, then you should remove the observer in the same method where you do that. You should probably remove all the observers either in viewDidDisappear or dealloc if you're navigating away from this controller.